# Interation of inner arraylist of arraylist of arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to make a arraylist of arraylists. My code is all over the place, I have just been adding stuff and trying trial by error. In the end what I'm trying to do is, say i have a car... it has speed, miles, mpg, and if they want to buy it add it to the arraylist of arraylists, and later be able to get a list of the cars owned, just to give you a idea of what I'm trying to do. idk if it helps, or maybe there's a better way to do it. I just need help with the iteration of the inner array, the rest i can figure out. Right now it just iterates the main arraylist and shows everything in there looking like a array. I rather use for loops then iterate class, but how ever it works is good for me.

```
public class Thelist {

    String a ="aa";
    String b ="bb";
    String c ="cc";

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> collection = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    static int count=0;
    ArrayList<String> listOfSomething1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void gg(){

    ArrayList<String> listOfSomething1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    listOfSomething1.add(a);
    listOfSomething1.add(b);
    listOfSomething1.add(c);

    collection.add(listOfSomething1);    
    count++;    
    }

    public void jk(int u){

    //this one feel like i can make new arraylist and use for loop for the collection size and iterate each one
    //but seems pretty hacky to me

        ArrayList<String> lis = new ArrayList<String>();
        lis.addAll(collection.get(u));

        for(int i=0;i<lis.size();i++ ){
          System.out.println("each "+i+" "+lis.get(i));
        }       
    }

    public void ll(){
        System.out.println(collection.size());
        System.out.println(collection.get(0).size());
    }

    public void ccc(String x,String y, String z){
        this.a= x;
        this.b=y;
        this.c=z;
    }

    public void remo(int r){

        collection.remove(0);
        count--;
    }

    public void getcount(){

        System.out.println("the count "+count); 

    }

    public void showall(){

        //this one shows all of the arraylist as arrays it looks like to me, I want each element
        // feel like i should be able to add another for loop to iterate over listOfSomething1
        //which is be add to the collection arraylist
        // but it don't work tryed for each too
        for(int i=0;i < collection.size();i++){
            System.out.println("uoo "+collection.get(i));

        }
    }
}






public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static int oo = 1;

Thelist ll = new Thelist();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   

}

public void woow(View v){

     String gg = Integer.toString(oo);
     ll.ccc("phi"+gg, "phil"+gg, "phily"+gg);   
     ll.gg();       
     oo++;
}


public void shoo(View v){

ll.showall();   
}

}
```

Comment: Look in your `gg()` method: you declare a new `ArrayList` and add to that rather than the field. No where do I see you adding to the field `listOfSomething1`, which is probably why iterating through it results in nothing

Comment: Please name your methods and variables appropiately. It helps people to see what you're trying to achieve, and thus enables them to provide better help for you.

Comment: @ Vince Emigh sorry I'm adding from my main class, just put the Thelist, sorry about that i will add a edit to make it clear for everyone else

Comment: @mike i know just in getting it to work mode, i have been changing it left and right just use whatever is quickest, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public void showall(){

        for(int i=0;i < collection.size();i++)
            for(int j=0; j< collection.get(i).size();j++)
              System.out.println(collection.get(i).get(j));

        }
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for... yea i seen you left out the ; j++ that's fine i got it, i will except your answer soon, just going to give everyone a few minutes just in case they are writing up answers, but this is exactly what i was looking for ty!!!

Answer (score 4):

Just use two nested for loops. The first iterates over the collection, yielding one `ArrayList<String>` per iteration. Take this list and iterate over it in the second iteration. For the sake of simplicity you can use for-each loops here:

```
for(ArrayList<String> cars : collection) {
    for(String car : cars) {
        System.out.println(car);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry went with Omar's answer, even though they are pretty much the same, just my preference of the setup... but thanks a lot i appreciate it!

Comment: Iterating over loops using indices is actually considered bad style in times of **for each**. For each abstracts from the underlying implementation and yields the best performance possible e.g. the `get` operation on a `LinkedList` (linear time complexity) is way slower compared to `ArrayList` (constant time complexity).